# AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture() method missing, retrieving picture (attachment) from MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, method-missing, axhost, getpicture

I'm trying to use AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture() to get a GIF image (saved as an attachment type) from MS Access 2013 database file (*.accdb) - convert it to Image so I can display it in a PictureBox. But the method is not there! :( Am I missing something? Do I need to set or install smtg?

Without conversion I get this error: "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Drawing.Image'"

Do I actually do the whole thing the right way? Or is there a better solution? Please, help me.

```
DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase("Database1.accdb", false, false, "");
Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("select solution from tab2 where id = 1", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset, 0, LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic);
rs.MoveFirst();

object o = rs.Fields[0].Value;
Image img = (Image)o; -> error
Image img = AxHost.GetPictureFromIPicture(o); - the method is missing
pictureBox1.Image = img;

rs.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [AxHost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says

> You typically do not use the AxHost class directly. You can use the Windows Forms ActiveX Control Importer (Aximp.exe) to generate the wrappers that extend AxHost.

I must admit that I have not tried that approach. To the best of my knowledge the only way to reliably extract a file from an Attachment field in an Access database is to use the `.SaveToFile()` method of an ACE DAO `Field2` object. In your case, the code would look something like this:

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string tempFileName;
    Image img;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
        Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\AttachmentsDB.accdb");
        Recordset rsMain = db.OpenRecordset(
                "select solution from tab2 where id = 1",
                RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot);
        Recordset2 rsAttach = rsMain.Fields["solution"].Value;
        tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + rsAttach.Fields["FileName"].Value;
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFileName);
        }
        catch { }
        Field2 fldAttach = (Field2)rsAttach.Fields["FileData"];
        fldAttach.SaveToFile(tempFileName);
        rsAttach.Close();
        rsMain.Close();
        db.Close();
        img = Image.FromFile(tempFileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        img.Dispose();
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempFileName);
    }

}
```